# DayJs - get difference in time from time A to time B

Tags: javascript, dayjs

Pretty standard problem, but what's different is this scenario:

I want to know the hours from `12:00 (timeA) to 20:00 (timeB)`. Simple `dayjs(timeA).diff(timeB, 'hours')` gives `8 hours`.

The problem is that when you do `20:00 to 02:00 midnight`, it will register as `18 hours` when in reality I want it to register `6 hours`.

Does anybody know how I can accomplish this with `dayJs`?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you dayjs converts the time you pass to it to the time of day. In the example below I've taken the dates and checked if `timeA` is after `timeB` in which case I add a day to `timeB` so the difference should be correct. This is only valid if the times you pass have a specific order, i.e. `timeA` comes before `timeB`.

```js
function getDiff(timeA, timeB) {
  const ta = dayjs(timeA, 'HH:mm');
  let tb = dayjs(timeB, 'HH:mm');

  if (ta.isAfter(tb)) tb = tb.add(1, 'd');

  const diff = dayjs(tb).diff(ta, 'hours');

  console.log(`the Diff from ${ta.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')}, ${tb.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')} is ${diff} hours`);
}

getDiff('12:00', '20:00');
getDiff('20:00', '02:00');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.8/plugin/customParseFormat.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dayjs@1/dayjs.min.js"></script>
<script>
  dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_customParseFormat)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I literally wrote out the post and realized I just do `24 - 18`. Rubber duck method I guess, but I'm posting just in case anyone else struggled to realize.